# In the film Chronicle, why do Matt and Steve get nosebleeds when Andrew strongly exerts his powers?

Tags: chronicle

In the film *Chronicle*, at a couple of points in the movie, Andrew will heavily use his powers or be under great stress.  This seems to trigger nosebleeds in Matt and Steve, although neither of them are using their powers.  How did this cause nosebleeds?  Usually nosebleeds were only triggered when they themselves were over-exerting their powers.

Comment: I can't help it.. I instantly flash on Alia, Lady Jessica and others suddenly having not-very believable nose-bleeds when Paul tries the Water of Life in Lynch's version of Dune.  (In the book no one knew what he had done; Jessica & Chandi figured it out a week or so later, with him in a coma.)  Possible they same thing; pointless, but dramatic and pointing to some underlying connection.

Comment: I just watched the movie over the weekend, and I came here with the exact same question.

Comment: I believe that Matt is stronger because when Andrew, at the end, threw a bus at Matt, he didn't take the damage even though he didn't know it was coming, and to use the barrier ability, they have to know the thing hits them is coming. Otherwise, it woudn't work. So Matt, while I think not as physically as strong as Steve or emotionally strong as Andrew, is the intellectual, making him not learn as easily, although figuring out more abilities than the others. Even though Andrew is the strongest at moving objects, he is the weakest physically and intellectually, so Matt would be the strongest>

Comment: I believe that Steve is the strongest as he learns how to fly first and suggested getting in the hole in the first place so he should get all the credit and that just because he got struck by lightning doesn't mean he isn't stronger than Matt or Andrew.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe all three had a telepathic bond with one another as their powers grew. Like how Steve knew exactly where Andrew was, knowing there was something wrong with him. What really had me thinking was that maybe these powers they draw on come from a shared source that they all eventually start feeling the effects of no matter who is exerting their power, such as Matt waking up with a terrible headache and nosebleed while stuff with Andrew was going on somewhere else. And finally when Matt knew something was terribly wrong with Andrew when he was in the hospital.

I really hope this doesn't turn into a superhero type series, I really liked how dark this was giving the feeling that the use of their powers were neither good nor bad. Makes for a good psychological thriller..

Answer (score -1):

They were telepathic and they said that in the movie and so they have full strength of the brain so they can move objects to fly they just move themselves so they can fly they also can use it as a way to read minds and find other people with the power it tells them when one of them is in danger when there noise bleeds so also it can be used for physical stuff that's how Andrew lifted his dad with one arm then threw him and also how when Andrew was in the hospital and his dad punched/hit he blocked it also the power can be used as a barrier that's how the fork didn't heart him.

Comment: and they had telekinesis

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

in the movie chronicle three friends gain telekenetic powers which over time increase in strength and power but when overdoing the powers they get nose bleeds but yet when andrew (one of the friends) use his power or is under stress the others noesbleeds too because not only are their powers gaining strength their bond is also, so when Andrew is under stress their bond effects the rest of them as a hive like mind.

Comment: Hello Freddie and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer the question. This is not a forum or a message board; instead we're looking for actual answers, preferably with references. Perhaps you'd like to take the [tour] to see what this site is all about?

Answer (score -3):

because andrew drained some of their power thats why in the end matt got his finger shot off because he didnt have enough energy to stop it and andrew is stronger because of he had his camera when they got there powers